# How to fetch hidden content using php web scraping

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping

I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser for web scraping, i can able to fetch content using file_get_html(''), But its not working for hidden content.

i am also want to fetch hidden content using scraping.

i also tried to fetch content using curl but it also unable to fetch hidden content.

For example:-

I want to fetch "**Happening now**" and "**Trending**" tab content from http://www.fastcompany.com/ website.

I am able to fetch "**Happening now**" tab, but it doesn't retrieve "**Trending**" tab data.

Here is my code:-

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$yesterday = date('Y/m/d',strtotime("-1 days"));
$html = file_get_html('http://www.fastcompany.com/homepage/'.$yesterday);
$res= $html->getElementById('sidebar-block-recommendation');


foreach($res->find('.recommendation-contents') as $result){
    foreach($result->find('li a') as $fl) {
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $fl; 
    }
}
?>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: What do you mean by hidden content? If it's in the DOM, you should be able to get it.

Comment: CSS has no effect on Simple HTML DOM Parser.

Comment: That content isn't hidden. It's loaded dynamically using AJAX. You need to use a Mechanize library to execute it.